# Convergence involving sub-exponential functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Does there exist any function $f(x)$ such that $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ can be satisfied:

**(1)** $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.

**(2)** $f(x)$ is sub-exponential function (i.e. $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\ln(f(x))}{x}=0$)

**(3)** $\forall d>0 $ (considered as a constant), $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} \neq 1$ or $\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)}$ does not converge when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

The motivation behind the above problem is that I am trying to find strictly increasing functions or sufficient conditions for strictly increasing functions to satisfy $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} = 1$. One necessary condition is (2) above since any exponetial function gives $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} < 1$.

What I have tried so far:

The first commonly used non-linear sub-exponential continuous functions are polynomial functions. Given any increasing polynomial functions, we can easily show that $(3)$ is not satisfied since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} = 1$.

Threfore, then I started to think about using piecewise functions which satisfies condition $(3)$. My current piecewise function is $f(x) =  \begin{cases}
                                   \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}x+\alpha & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq d$} \\
                                   f(x-d)\dfrac{f(d)}{f(0)} & \text{if $d <x \leq 2d$} \\
  f(x-d)\dfrac{f(x-d)}{f(x-2d)} & \quad \! \! \text{ otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

where $\alpha>1$, $\beta<1$ (for example, $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 0.001$, and $d=4$). We can show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} = \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \neq 1$ and this function is also increasing. However, this piecewise function can be approximately by exponetial function when $x$ is large, which violates the condition $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x) = e^{[\ln(x)]} x .$$
Here $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$.  Note that by considering the sequence $x_n = e^n - d/2 $, we see that
$$ \liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} \le  e^{-1} .$$

Note, if the limit exists and
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} < 1 ,$$
then there exists $x_0$ such that for $x \ge x_0$
$$ \sup_{x \ge x_0} \frac{f(x)}{f(x+d)} \le \frac 1L < 1 .$$
Thus $f(x_0+nd) \ge L^n f(x_0)$, or for $x \ge x_0$
$$ f(x) \ge L^{(x-x_0)/d - 1} f(x_0) $$
and it is not possible for $f$ to be sub-exponential.